# Selenium Sometimes Succeeds in Clicking Sub Menu Item

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having one of those scenarios with Selenium where it sometimes works.

The flow I’m focusing on is pretty simple and this has been asked and answered several times.

Hover over main menu item
Move to and click on sub menu item.

Here is the code:

Any advice as to how I could make this work every time would be most appreciated.

```
var actions = new Actions(SeleniumTestDriver.WebDriver);
// Move to the Main Menu Element and hover  
actions.MoveToElement(SeleniumTestDriver.WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(@"//*[@id='main_menu']/ul/li[3]/a"))).Perform();

Thread.Sleep(1000); 

var wait = new WebDriverWait(SeleniumTestDriver.WebDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
var subMenuLink = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath(@"//*[@id='main_menu']/ul/li[3]/ul/li[4]/a")));

Thread.Sleep(250);
actions.MoveToElement(subMenuLink).Click().Perform();
```

**Version Details:**
Firefox v33.1
Selenium.WebDriver 2.44.0
Selenium.Support 2.44.0
Language C#

**Edit by op**

I should also add that when it fails, the menu flashes, as if the hover has been interrupted. Opens and shuts too quickly for the sub-menu item to be clicked.

The Html for that menu is:

```
<nav id="main_menu" class="ddsmoothmenu">
    <ul class="primary_menu">
        <li><a href="/webinar/calendar">calendar</a></li>
        <li class="parent" style="z-index: 100;">...</li>
        <li class="parent" style="z-index: 99;">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="">Upcoming Webinars<i></i></a>
            <ul style="top: 95px; visibility: visible; left: 0px; width: 195px; display: none;">
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/Webinar/Details/4567">Best-Ever Compliance Checklists For...</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/Webinar/Details/4572">Build a No-Excuses Sales Environmen...</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/Webinar/Details/4560">Handling Power of Attorney Document...</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/Webinar/Details/4566">Flood Insurance</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/Webinar/Details/4562">Opening Accounts for Nonresident Al...</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/Webinar/Details/4561">New Share Member Account Interview ...</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/Webinar/allActive/?eventsToShow=upcoming">
                        <font color="green">View <b>All</b> Upcoming Events</font>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="parent" style="z-index: 98;">...</li>
        <li style="z-index: 97;">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="">About Us<i></i></a>
            <ul style="display: none; top: 95px; visibility: visible;">
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/Home/WhatIsAWebinar">What Is A Webinar?</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/Home/CommonQuestions">Commonly Asked Questions</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/Home/DetailedConnectionInstructions">Connecting to Your Webinar</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/Home/contactus">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>       
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Thanks

Comment: Try increasing the timeout to 10 seconds and also use [Relative xpaths rather than Absolute one](http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xpathrelative.php)

Comment: @Subh thanks for the suggestion. But it still only works sometimes. Then other times, even with the 1st wait, the menu flashes as if the hover has been interrupted. My hands are off the keyboard and mouse at all times.

Comment: **Replace the code** `actions.MoveToElement(SeleniumTestDriver.WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(@"//*[@id='main_menu']/ul/li[3]/a"))).Perform();` **with** `actions.MoveToElement(SeleniumTestDriver.WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(@"//*[@id='main_menu']/ul/li[3]/a"))).Build().Perform();` and try please

Comment: @Subh thanks again, but adding Build() did not solve the problem.

Comment: Okay.. Then, please add the relevant HTML code snippet of the menu and submenu. It will be easier to sort it out then.

Comment: @Subh I've added html for the majority of the menu. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the xpath of your existing code. Please check if that works for you:

```
var actions = new Actions(SeleniumTestDriver.WebDriver);
// Move to the Main Menu Element and hover  
actions.MoveToElement(SeleniumTestDriver.WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[@class='parent']/a[.='Upcoming Webinars']"))).Build().Perform();

var wait = new WebDriverWait(SeleniumTestDriver.WebDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
var subMenuLink = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//li[@role='presentation']/a[contains(text(),'Flood Insurance')]")));

actions.MoveToElement(subMenuLink).Click().Perform();
```

Comment: sorry for the delay. Alas, it worked once, but then subsequent tests reverted to the old behaviour.

Comment: By subsequent tests, do you mean you are running the code one after another, after each execution is over?

Comment: @onefootswill : Also, please do mention what error(s) are you getting when the click isn't happening ?

Comment: sorry, I meant that 5 tests runs one after the other and each invoke the method to click on the SubMenuItem. The error is a NoSuchElementException and it states Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='RegistrationType']/dl/dt[3]/input"} and strangley one fail was a bit different {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='RegistrationType']/dl/dt[5]/input"} .

Comment: apologies, but I have to go offline for a while. Meetings. Less fun.

Comment: OKay.. you mean, each time you are trying to select a different option from dropdown list. I mean it will select **"Best-Ever Compliance Checklists For..." in the first run** then **"Build a No-Excuses Sales Environmen..." in the second run**, **Handling Power of Attorney Document..." in the third run**, and so on. Is that correct ?

Comment: not quite. It is meant to select the same SubMenuItem in each test. The idea being, it navigates to the same Details page for each test and then the tests varies slightly on that page to account for different flows. But to get there, it has to first hover on the primary and select the particular SubMenuItem.

I have no idea why it was selecting different items in the last run with the latest code, because the same code is executed for each test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65949/discussion-between-subh-and-onefootswill).

Comment: Sorry for falling asleep in chat room. Was late here. But it is working with the JavascriptExecutor, so big thanks.

Comment: it could have been done without javascriptExecutor cause the only reason your code was failing was that u didn't put click on first moveToElement in order to make the dropdown visible for webdriver...

Comment: @VivekSingh: I tried with clicking too.. It worked for the first time, and then afterwards the same result. That's why I suggested **JavascriptExecutor** to him.

Comment: @Subh: I ran the script for multiple times it worked cool...might be something on his end...

Comment: @VivekSingh : That's a mystery for me too.. :) Anyways, it got sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

please try it out with below code:

```
WebElement web = dri.findElement(By
        .xpath("//a[contains(.,'Upcoming Webinars')]"));
Actions objA = new Actions(dri);
objA.moveToElement(web).click().build().perform();
objA.moveToElement(
    (new WebDriverWait(dri, 3)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By
        .xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Safe Deposit Boxes')]"))))
    .click().build().perform();
```

You cab replace `Safe Deposit Boxes` with your own choice of element to be clicked.

**P.S. Sorry but this code is in java, please help yourself for any equivalent in C#.**